# Unable to describe Kafka Streams Consumer Group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

What I want to achieve is to be sure that my Kafka streams consumer does not have lag.

I have simple Kafka streams application that materialized one topic as store in form of GlobalKTable.

When I try to describe consumer on Kafka by command:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-application-id
```

I can't see any results. And there is no error either. When I list all consumers by:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --all-groups
```

my application consumer is listed correctly.

Any idea where to find additional information what is happening that I can't describe consumer?
(Any other Kafka streams consumers that write to topics can be described correctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application does *only* materialize a topic into a `GlobalKTable` no consumer group is formed. Internally, the "global consumer" does not use `subscribe()` but `assign()` and there is no consumer `group.id` configured (as you can verify from the logs) and no offset are committed.

The reason is, that all application instances need to consume all topic partitions (ie, broadcast pattern). However, a consumer group is designed such that different instances read different partitions for the same topic. Also, per consumer group, only one offset can be committed per partition -- however, if multiple instance read the same partition and would commit offsets using the same `group.id` the commits would overwrite each other.

Hence, using a consumer group while "broadcasting" data does not work.

However, all consumers should expose a "lag" metrics `records-lag-max` and `records-lag` (cf https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumer_fetch_monitoring). Hence, you should be able to hook in via JMX to monitor the lag. Kafka Streams includes client metrics via `KafkaStreams#metrics()`, too.