# Kafka consumer group description does not include all topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka application with application.id = X. The application consumes from 6 input topics. Topics A, B, C are consumed as Kstream. Topics D, E, F each has a single partition and is consumed as a GlobalKTable. When I run

> kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group X

I can only see topics A, B, C.

```
GROUP           TOPIC             PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                                           HOST            CLIENT-ID
X               A                 0          181127          181127          0               X-38d9b9f7-fb7e-4feb-8892-563d2505d2bd-StreamThread-1-consumer-0b215406-4caf-4b42-ba59-412b11ef357f /127.0.0.1      X-38d9b9f7-fb7e-4feb-8892-563d2505d2bd-StreamThread-1-consumer
X               B                 0          19446           19451           5               X-38d9b9f7-fb7e-4feb-8892-563d2505d2bd-StreamThread-1-consumer-0b215406-4caf-4b42-ba59-412b11ef357f /127.0.0.1      X-38d9b9f7-fb7e-4feb-8892-563d2505d2bd-StreamThread-1-consumer
X               C                 0          -               0               -               X-38d9b9f7-fb7e-4feb-8892-563d2505d2bd-StreamThread-1-consumer-0b215406-4caf-4b42-ba59-412b11ef357f /127.0.0.1      X-38d9b9f7-fb7e-4feb-8892-563d2d2505d2bd-StreamThread-1-consumer
```

From the logs, I'm certain my application is consuming messages from the topics D, E, F.

Why are the topics D, E, F missing from the description? 
How can I get lag info on these topics?

Comment: You'll only see topics that have committed offsets. Tables are rebuilt from the beginning when (re)started (have no committed offset)

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61525179/unable-to-describe-kafka-streams-consumer-group